# Firebird and IBCTable

Tags: delphi, firebird, auto-increment

I am trying the devart ibdac components but I am having a little issue with the IBCTable component. On tables with autoinc (trigger based) when I try to post the data it says that the field with the autoincrement must have a value, whereas if I use a SQL query to insert it everything works fine.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the following properties for the `TIBCTable` component to automatically fill out the fields with values from the same generator / sequence that you use in your trigger:

- `GeneratorMode`
- `GeneratorStep`
- `KeyFields`
- `KeyGenerator`

For more information see the documentation of the `TIBCTable` component, you will find all the properties with links to the base class they are introduced in.